# Obter valores de um json / objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho o seguinte json:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E 2 selects, um para estado e outro para cidade, já preenchi o de estado corretamente usando este json:

```
        //combobox estados
    $.getJSON('http://api.doupenglish.com.br/unidades', function (unidades) {
        var selectestado = $("#selectestado");
        var selectcidade = $("#selectcidade");

        var estados = unidades.Estados;
        //não consigo recuperar as cidades do json aqui
        var cidades = unidades.Estados.values;

        // console.log(cidades)
        var optionsestados = '<option hidden >Selecione um estado</option>';
        $.each(estados, function (estado) {
            optionsestados += '<option value="' + estado + '">' + estado + '</option>';
        });
        selectestado.html(optionsestados);
        selectestado.change(function () {
            var estadoselecionado;
            selectestado.find("option:selected").each(function () {
                estadoselecionado = $(this).text();
                console.log(estadoselecionado)
            });

        })

    });
```

Preciso que ao selecionar um estado ele liste todas as cidades daquele estado, o problema é que eu não estou consigo obter a "lista" de cidades neste json, tentei varias coisas porem sem sucesso.
Não sei se é o json que ta mal "formatado" mas como nao possuo um chave para as cidades, não consigo acessar.

---

EDIT
Consegui obter um objeto com as cidades:

```
 $.each(estados, function (estado, cidades) {
                    if (estado === estadoselecionado){
                        console.log(cidades)
                    }
                });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem ainda não consigo obter os valores deste objeto como nome, rua etc

Comment: tentou `data[0].bairro` ?

Comment: @adventistaam sim, da erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bairro' of undefined

Comment: se você colocar no retorno javascript `console.log( data )` o que retorna?

Comment: nao utilizo a variavel com nome data, mas acho q você ta se referindo ao json recebido com nome de unidades, então me retorna isto: http://prntscr.com/ioq50o

Comment: O json completo mesmo

Comment: Na verdade data significa dado em ingles, tente `cidades[0].bairro` o que acontece?

Comment: Exatamente igual meu primeiro comentário ( ja tinha feito com cidades)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74226/discussion-between-adventistaam-and-igor-oliveira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar os valores de rua, número, e-mail, etc, você tem que fazer um `for each` dentro do outro, por exemplo:

```
selectestado.change(function() {
    let estadoselecionado = $(this).val();

    $.map(estados[estadoselecionado], function (cidades) {
        $.map(cidades, function (enderecos) {
            console.log( `Rua: ${enderecos.rua}, ${enderecos.numero}` )
        });
    });
})
```

Mas se você quiser apenas pegar o nome das cidades, basta utilizar:

```
selectestado.change(function() {
    let estadoselecionado = $(this).val();

    $.map(estados[estadoselecionado], function (cidades, cidade) {
        console.log( cidade )
    });
})
```

Comment: funcionou, map e each são a mesma coisa?

Comment: @IgorOliveira  Não, esse métodos são diferentes. O `each` é utilizado para objetos imutáveis, já o `map` é mais utilizado quando desejamos retornar um array com os novos valores (sim, o `map` também serve para filtrar os valores). Mas ambos percorrem `arrays`, `objetos` etc. Atualizei o exemplo para ficar mais condizente.

Comment: Só uma coisa, com o each nao  funciona, apenas com map como estava antes